# bash "read" command to suppress interpretation of "\"

Tags: bash, find, escaping

I have some lines that have "\" and are piped to "read" in a bash script. Somehow "read" removes the "\". How can I make "read" take the input literally without trying to interpret "\" ?

```
$ find TestDir -type f -print
TestDir/1 2 \3 $4 5
TestDir/\- * 5 %
TestDir/1 2 \3 
TestDir/A B $ ( 1 )/3 4 (h) # ~/a { 2 }
TestDir/A B $ ( 1 )/3 4 (h) # ~/[1 @]/4 .9 ( )
TestDir/A B $ ( 1 )/\- ( * ) $ 4
```

Passing lines with "\" to "read" :

```
$ find TestDir -type f -print | while IFS= read aFile; do ls -l "$aFile" ; done
ls: cannot access 'TestDir/1 2 3 $4 5': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'TestDir/- * 5 %': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'TestDir/1 2 3 ': No such file or directory
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Jul 17 10:47 'TestDir/A B $ ( 1 )/3 4 (h) # ~/a { 2 }'
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Jul 17 10:47 'TestDir/A B $ ( 1 )/3 4 (h) # ~/[1 @]/4 .9 ( )'
ls: cannot access 'TestDir/A B $ ( 1 )/- ( * ) $ 4': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use the `read` with the `-r` option.

Comment: If you have filenames with funny characters, it's safest to use null characters as delimiters between them, like `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' aFile; do ...` See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)

Comment: Thank you very much M. Nejat Aydin and Gordon Davisson !

Comment: Furthermore, this kind of pipeline can often be made easier by using "-exec" on the find command. Like this: `find ... -exec ls -l "{}" \;`, but the "ls -l" part could be anything you want to do to each find result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use `read` with the `-r` option:

Excerpt of manpage of `read` command

> -r     do not allow backslashes to escape any characters

Hope my answer helps!